# revision number difference on hudson job

Tags: numbers, hudson, revision

I found there is difference between the revision number shown at "Status" of a particular job and "At revision" of the build console output of a job on hudson.
  When i trigger a build, even if they are no new checkins in repository, the revision will be 
incremented and new revision number will be seen in the console output of the job("At revision"), for the same,  when i click the "Status" of the same job for the same build, the revision number doesn't change and its correct, only when the change or new checkins happened in the repository that correct revison number its showing up.

Can anyone tell why this difference is, hudson i use is 2.2.0, hudson-Subversion plugin-2.2.0-1.

Answer (score 0):

What i've noticed is that "At revision" from the console log shows the latest revision of the whole repository, i.e. at the root of the repository.

The build job page correctly shows the revision of the actual SVN path that you are checking out.

Incidentally, the SVN_REVISION or the SVN_REVISION_1 shows the corrects revision (of your actual checkout path) as well